# Insert .csv file to SQL Server using OpenRowSet

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a .csv file, called File1 that I would like insert into my already existing table, called Table1 within SQL Server. The .csv file has the following structure and values:

```
 ID        Location        Name        Date

 2         New York        Sally       20191010
 3         California      Ben         20191110
```

My table within SQL server has the same structure:

```
 ID         Location        Name         Date

 1          Houston         Kelly        20200810
```

I wish for output to look like the value below, I wish for the date to be in order as well.

```
ID     Location    Name     Date

1      Houston     Kelly    20200810
2      New York    Sally    20191010
3      California  Ben      20191110
```

I am doing this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB12.0; Database = 'Data', 
'SELECT * FROM OpenRowSet' Dir = C:\downloads, 'SELECT * FROM File1.csv')
```

I am still researching to see what it is I am doing wrong with the above command. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps:

```
BULK INSERT Table_1
FROM 'C:\Folder\file.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',   --Use to shift the control to next row
FORMAT = 'CSV'
)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try. Is this better than doing the INSERT command?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are different methods to insert from csv file into database, but I like BULK insert better because it can be minimally logged operation so would be faster

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it is saying: Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.) I am researching this

Comment: this error is because sql does not have access to the folder you have the csv file, move it from Downloads to another folder

Comment: Ok, I created new folder and same error. I am still researching this

Comment: Right Click on the folder>Properties>Security>Group Or Usernames click on Edit>Add look for the user sql serer is running under. then give full control access to the user and click done. it should do it

Comment: Hm ok, it says I have full access (When I searched for my name)

Comment: Ok when I go to folder-properties-security , I only see system , my name and administrators(with my server listed) and when I go to edit- allow permissions is checked for all

Comment: Thank you, it worked, when I moved the .csv file somewhere in the C drive. I didn't have to change/add permissions. Thank you!

Comment: I think you have to add 'Firstrow = 2' to avoid the duplicate column titles as well